# Selecting item on JComboBox contained on a cell of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I have created a JComboBox and I am using it on a column of a JTable - see code below.

```
Object[] items = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(items);
comboBox.setRenderer(new customComboBoxRenderer());
myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(Table.CONF_COL).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

Now, my problem is that I cannot find a way to make each combo box in the column of the table with the combo boxes to have an initial value (might be different on each combo box) which will also be the selected item of the particular combo box when the program starts.
I think the problem is being created because the JTable is using only one JComboBox instance for all the cells of the column and therefore I can never get a different instance of combo box for each of the cells on the column and set the selected item to them.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Many thanks,

Soc

Answer (score 2):

- read Oracle tutorial [How to use Tables - Using a Combo Box as an Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) for working code example
- everything depends of value stored in `DefaultComboBoxModel`, in your case I'd be store `Integer` not `String` value for `JComboBox`es model
- value stored in `XxxTableModel` representing selected or inital value in `JComboBox` as `TableCellEditor`,
- there you can store Integer value too, to avoiding any parsing between String and Integer
- simple use (`JTable` or `XxxTableModel`).`setValueAt` to display desired value in `JTable` (painted by `TableCellRenderer`)
- more info about `TableCellRenderer` and `TableCellEditor` in Oracle tutorial

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have quite good knowledge of the things that you have mentioned However, whatever I do I get the same combo box on each cell of the column and that creates a problem for me. The problem is that each combo box of a cell of the column would have as a default the same selected item since they use the same combo box. Therefore even thought the combo box might show another item, it will reset it to the default (on first user click) which for some combo boxes is correct and for some it is not. My solution was a list to store the initial values of each combo box.

Answer (score 0):

In your `customComboBoxRenderer`

call `setSelectedItem(same type as your jcombobox elements, in this case String)`

inside your

`getTableCellRendererComponent(.. )` method

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain your answer in more detail.